# Docker: prevent container from modifying host's files when binding

Tags: docker, filesystems

Whenever I bind a filesystem to a docker container using `-v`:

```py
sudo docker ... run -v /file/to/host/thing:/container/filepath ...
```

Any modification my container does to it's corresponding `/container/filepath`, that gets mirrored onto the host's filesystem. This is obviously by design, and what "mounting" means.

However, I want a way where the container *starts* off with a copy of `/file/to/host/thing` on `/container/filepath` where it can modify the latter all it wants as long as the changes remains **isolated** within the container itself.

The `:ro` suffix to the filepath makes the entire container's files `read-only`. For my use-case, this is undesirable as I want to modify some of the files.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Can you `COPY` the directory into your image, and not mount it as a volume?  Then it will exist in the container-temporary filesystem and have the behavior you want.

Comment: That could work @DavidMaze. care you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container temporary filesystem has the copy-on-write behavior you describe, provided you do *not* mount something over it.  If you `COPY` the content into your Docker image, each container will start from the content in the image but have its own isolated copy of it if it does need to write to this.

For this to work, in the Dockerfile you need to add a `COPY` line to copy the content into the image (as with other `COPY` commands, the data must exist inside the Docker build context; you cannot use an arbitrary host directory) and you need to remove the `docker run -v` option.

The other important caveat is that, if you are building `FROM` a base image that declares a `VOLUME`, you cannot un-`VOLUME` that directory and get the copy-on-write behavior back.  In the specific case of a database container, for example, you cannot create a database image with preseeded data and have non-persistent copy-on-write behavior without changing the database storage location (as much as this does sound very useful for some kinds of integration tests and for some application frameworks like Rails).

Comment: But that won't update the filesystem through `COPY` everytime a container is spun up - correct?

Comment: Correct.  You'd have to rebuild the image with the reference copy of the data.